# Linux screen program: determining the communication details of a working connection

Tags: gnu-screen

I am trouble shooting an issue with a PySerial program which interfaces a step motor via terminal emulation, and going back to the use of screen as a known working interface.

When I connect to the serial-USB adapter on /dev/ttyUSB* using the program screen, I
have a working connection with the step motor and everything works as expected. That means I can set a user variable and reset it with no problem.

When I try to use my PySerial implementation, I can set the user variables only once before an error is thrown.

I am therefore attempting to rule out a communication protocol problem by comparing the settings used by the screen program with those of my Python program.

The heart of my question, is that I do not know how to examine the full com parameters of screen when it is connected to the /dev/ttyUSB* ports.

Comment: The man pges state that when connected to a device, such as ttya, the com protocols are guessed by the driver and stored in a previous connection file. My installation ( Mint 13 ) does not have a .screenrc file in my home, nor can I find one yet.

Comment: It turns out that com settings were not the cause of my problem. pySerial is a pretty good test of what connections parameters work, or what they do.